# Field Reference in update record of process builder is not working in deployed Org

Tags: managed-package, process-builder

I have a process builder which update the record of object A on creation or updation of record of object A. The field which I am updating text field. In process builder, I am populating its value with field reference. The reference field has a master relationship with object B which again has master relation with object C.Like *customB__c.customC__c.name*. This reference is updating the field in org where it is created but it is giving an error  (The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow)  if we deploy it into another org through a managed package. 
 On another hand, if I am trying to implement this procedure using *Formula* instead of *Field Reference*. It will work in the same org as well as in deployed org.

Comment: Probably failed because 1 of the lookup is null (either customB__c or customC__c). You should add check in the process builder step that those fields are not null.

Comment: Both lookups are filled. No null value is there. I have checked that. I think there is some kind of field level security because in some orgs it is working fine but in some, it is throwing the error.

Comment: Process builder run in system mode, therefore the field level security shouldn't cause the issue.

Comment: I know that process builder run in the system mode. I am facing this issue in some orgs where I have deployed the package but not in all orgs.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to put the null check for the Lookup field and also check the FLS for the Used fields that are being referred in the process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please note that you [shouldn't link to your own website like this](/help/promotion).